# Iterate Excel Formula Cell Ranges down 24

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 4 columns: Hour, Date, Prediction, and Actual. I'm trying to first find the Hour that corresponds to the highest aActual value for the day. I have done this through:

```
=MATCH(MAX(D2:D25),D2:D25,0)
```

Next I'm trying to find the Hour that corresponds to the highest Prediction value for the day, as well as the hours that correspond to the second, third, fourth, and fifth highest hours of the day. I have done the first step through:

```
=MATCH(MAX(C2:C25),C2:C25,0)
```

As and the second/third/fourth/fifth steps through (example is for second step):

```
=MATCH(LARGE(C2:C25,2),C2:C25,0)
```

My problem is that I want to repeat this for every day on my dataset range, which would require iterating/shifting the ranges downwards in the formula by 24, and I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. I've tried just using addition to the cell values but that didn't work (needless to say I'm not the best with excel). Any help is appreciated! I've attached a screenshot of my spreadsheet for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the INDIRECT() formula to chose the range. Replace your formulas for the following for the first day and then copy them down:

```
=MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("D"&(row(a1)-1)*24+2&":D"&row(a1)*24+1)),INDIRECT("D"&(row(a1)-1)*24+2&":D"&row(a1)*24+1),0)

=MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("C"&(row(a1)-1)*24+2&":C"&row(a1)*24+1)),INDIRECT("C"&(row(a1)-1)*24+2&":C"&row(a1)*24+1),0)

=MATCH(LARGE(INDIRECT("C"&(row(a1)-1)*24+2&":C"&row(a1)*24+1),2),INDIRECT("C"&(row(a1)-1)*24+2&":C"&row(a1)*24+1),0)
```

As an example, for Day 3, C50:C73 is created the following way (3rd row):

```
INDIRECT("C"&(row(a3)-1)*24+2&":C"&row(a3)*24+1)
```

Reference Row(a3) is = 3, then:

```
INDIRECT("C"&(3-1)*24+2&":C"&3*24+1)
INDIRECT("C"&50&":C"&73)
INDIRECT("C50:C73")
```